# Android : Intent for viewing multiple images

Tags: android, intentfilter

My activity enables to display a gallery of images and I want to define an "intent filter", indicating that my apps can open several images. For example, after an user takes pictures and wants to browse it, a chooser dialog should propose my apps.

I know that this code, in the manifest, works for just one image :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But it does not work for several images...

I think that the value of the mimetype is not correct...but what is the correct mimetype to open the image of the media provider ?

Here is an example of an intent filter to view google.note :

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
</intent-filter>
```

I try to replace "note" with "image", but it does not work...any idea ?

I finally get the source code of the Gallery project, here, the manifest file : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But it does not work anyway on my Nexus S...

And I found this on the Android developper site :

> For multiple records:

```
vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.yourcompanyname.contenttype
```

> For example, a request for all train records, like the following URI,

```
content://com.example.transportationprovider/trains
```

> might return this MIME type:

```
vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.rail
```

Comment: do you mean that you want a multiple image in one layout?

Comment: I mean I display a matrix of images on the same view, a gridview for example.

Comment: so what s problem ? why you not use greed view

Answer (score 0):

The default Image Viewer doesn't have such an API exposed. And the format or data would differ from application to application. There isn't a general solution for this which would work with every application.

The best way, perhaps is to write a small activity yourself, which exposes an intent that takes in a array of Uris and shows thumbnails of all of those images.

When you click on a thumbnail, you can launch the single image intent to see that particular image.

---

Here you go:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
```

Got it from the Android source code. Should have looked there before.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It is very strange because on my Nexus S, when I switch from the camera to an image viewer, a dialog chooser opens and proposes me several applications : quickpic or Gallery 3D...so it seems possible...

Comment: Well, Those applications suggest  to view all your images. That's quite possible. But, viewing a specific list of images, is something different. Ok, I will get back to this in some time.

Comment: The ImageViewer from the Camera App, launches an Intent with a single image link, that's the last image that you captured. For me, it shows only one image, and not all the images.

Comment: In fact, I want to display all the images :). And if I select the gallery, it shows me all the image. That is the same for quickPic.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, the default gallery focus on one image passed in the intent but all the images are available.